# Python list comprehension with rockets

Tags: python

I need to print out a list of rockets with their own positions (x and y) using list comprehension (need to use list comprehension for homework).

I have an issue currently when I print the list, it first prints (0,0) for 9 times before it prints the assigned x and y values for each rocket.  I am very new to python, so please bear with me.

```
class Rocket:
    ## Fill in the rest of the class definition

  def __init__ (self, x=0,y=0):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y

       
  def moveup(self):
        self.y += 1
```

```
rocket = Rocket(0,0)
print("Starting position is " , rocket.x, rocket.y)


direction = input("What direction do you want to go?")

if direction == "up":
     print("you went up")
     rocket.moveup()
     print("Position: ", rocket.x, rocket.y)

else:
      print("Nothing happened")


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

rockets = [Rocket() for x in range(0,10)]

rockets.append(Rocket(0,0))
rockets.append(Rocket(1,1))
rockets.append(Rocket(2,2))
rockets.append(Rocket(3,3))
rockets.append(Rocket(4,4))
rockets.append(Rocket(5,5))
rockets.append(Rocket(6,6))
rockets.append(Rocket(7,7))
rockets.append(Rocket(8,8))
rockets.append(Rocket(9,9))

for rocket in rockets:
  print(rocket.x,rocket.y)
```

my output is :

```
Starting position is  0 0
What direction do you want to go?up
you went up
Position:  0 1
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

I think I partially know what is going on, when I first make the list it makes, each rocket 0,0 and when I append, it creates a new rocket instead of editing them.  I guess my main question is how do I edit an index of the array to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the list comprehension and the appends. Just initialize the list with the rockets you want in the list comprehension

```
rockets = [Rocket(i, i) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: The issue is I have to use list comprehension for an assignment.  I forgot to mention it in my post, my apologies.

Comment: @AMCode96 He means you don't need **both**. Get rid of the append lines and just use the list comprehension shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

please observe that when calling

```
rockets = [Rocket() for x in range(0,10)]
```

you create 10 instances of class `Rocket` and put them on the list `rockets`. Call is supplied with no parameters an thus default values are used as defined in constructor (`Rocket: ... def __init__ (self, x=0,y=0)`).

This is equivalent to calling `rockets.append(Rocket(0, 0))` 10 times. Then you create the remaining 10 by hand

```
rockets.append(Rocket(0,0))
...
rockets.append(Rocket(9,9))
```

so the output is justified

> and when I append, it creates a new rocket instead of editing them

That`s exactly what it does .You may want to use array subscription to get the object from an array to use its methods or edit its properties
e.g.

```
for r in rockets:
    r.moveup()

for r in rockets:
    r.x = r.y*r.y
```